# Roslyn / MSBuildWorkspace Does Not Load Documents on Non-Dev Computer

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

MSBuildWorkspace does now show documents on computers other than the one I'm using to build the application.

I have seen [Roslyn workspace for .NET Core's new .csproj format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395336/roslyn-workspace-for-net-cores-new-csproj-format), but in my case, it works fine on the development computer (Documents is populated), but it is empty for the same project on a different computer.

**So I am not sure why it would work on my development computer, but not on my other computer...?**

This is the code :

```
    public static IReadOnlyList<CodeFile> ReadSolution(string path)
    {
        List<CodeFile> codes = new List<CodeFile>();
        using (MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
        {
            var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(path).Result;
            foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
            {
                //project.Documents.Count() is 0
                foreach (var doc in project.Documents)
                {
                    if (doc.SourceCodeKind == SourceCodeKind.Regular)
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
                        {
                            var source = doc.GetTextAsync().Result;
                            source.Write(sw);
                            sw.WriteLine();
                        }

                        codes.Add(new CodeFile(doc.FilePath, sb.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return codes;
    }
```

Comment: MSBuild workspace needs msbuild installed and all the required msbuild task files for csharp/vb in order to work. It will likely only work in an app executing under a developer command prompt (one where msbuild.exe also works.)  You will also need to include all the binding redirects found in msbuild.exe.config in your own app.confg.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the newer versions of MSBuildWorkspace no long throw exceptions on failures, instead raising an event, WorkspaceFailure. (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15056)

This indicated that the required build tools (v15 / VS2017) were not available. The new 2017 Build Tools installer is both too complicated for our end users and much slower to install than the 2015 build tools installer was.

Instead, I came up with this less robust method to avoid that dependency:

```
    public static IReadOnlyList<CodeFile> ReadSolution(string path)
    {
        List<CodeFile> codes = new List<CodeFile>();

        var dirName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);
        var csProjFiles = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.csproj", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach(var csProjFile in csProjFiles)
        {
            var csProjPath = csProjFile.Directory.FullName;
            using (var fs = new FileStream(csProjFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fs))
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        if(reader.Name.Equals("Compile", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            var fn = reader["Include"];
                            var filePath = Path.Combine(csProjPath, fn);
                            var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                            codes.Add(new CodeFile(fn,text));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return codes;
    }
```

Comment: If you don't execute the project file via MSBuild, you won't know about any generated files or what the correct set of references are.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem
I was using a .Net Core Console App.

I noticed that Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild had the warning:

Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild 2.10.0 was restored using '.Net Framework,version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NetCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.  this package may not be fully compatible with your project.

I changed to a .Net Framework Console App and I could access the documents.